# Memory pools implementation in C

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, allocation, pool

I am looking for a good memory pool implementation in C.

it should include the following:

1. Anti fragmentation.
2. Be super fast :)
3. Ability to "bundle" several allocations from different sizes under some identifier and delete all the allocations with the given identifier.
4. Thread safe

Comment: Do you mean you would like to find a library with these properties? Or information on how to implement it yourself?

Comment: I'd like to find library with these properties :)

Comment: Are you restricted to C or can ou also use C++ ?

Comment: Are you sure you need anything like this? Have you identified a problem with the OS/compiler-supplied memory-management tools?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the excellent [`talloc`](http://talloc.samba.org/talloc/doc/html/index.html), developed as part of samba might be what you're looking for.  The part I find most interesting is that any pointer returned from talloc is a valid memory context.  Their example is:

```
struct foo *X = talloc(mem_ctx, struct foo);
X->name = talloc_strdup(X, "foo");
// ...
talloc_free(X); // frees memory for both X and X->name
```

In response to your particular points:

(1) Not sure what anti-fragmentation is in this case.  In C you're not going to get compacting garbage collection anyway, so I think your choices are somewhat limited.

(2) It advertises being only 4% slower than plain `malloc(3)`, which is quite fast.

(3) See example above.

(4) It is thread safe as long as different threads use different contexts & the underlying malloc is thread safe.

Comment: This is the closest to what i needed. i ended up with developing my own solution though, since it has very specific needs. i might publish it under opensource project.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into

- nedmalloc http://www.nedprod.com/programs/portable/nedmalloc/
- ptmalloc http://www.malloc.de/en/

Both leverage a memory pool but keep it mostly transparent to the user.

In general, you will find best performance in your own custom memory pool (you can optimize for your pattern).  I ended up writing a few for different access patterns.

Comment: i thought they both basically ripped from dlmalloc :)

Answer (score 2):

For memory pools that have been thoroughly tried and tested you may want to just use the APR ones:

http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.4/apr__pools_8h.html

Mind you, single pools are not thread safe, you'll have to handle that yourself.

Answer (score -1):

bget is another choice. It's well tested and production ready.

http://www.fourmilab.ch/bget/